# How can I get my program to capitalize the first letter of a sentence?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have to make my program capitalize the first letter of a sentence and for some reason my code isn't working. I don't know why - my code looks like it's supposed to work and I know better to blame a "possible" bug in Java for my inexperience. Here is what I got so far:

```
public class SentenceFormator {
    public static String format(String str){
        String fmts = str;
        String temp;

        //Finds first subString makes it capitalized and replaces it in original String.
        temp = fmts.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        fmts = fmts.replaceFirst(fmts.substring(0,1), temp);
        //Makes all other letters after beginning of sentence lower-case.
        fmts = fmts.substring(1,str.length()-1).toLowerCase();
        //Capitalizes all i's in the String.
        fmts = fmts.replaceAll(" i ", " I ");
        //Take away white spaces at the end and beginning of the String.
        fmts = fmts.trim();
        //Add punctuation if not already there. 
        if(!fmts.endsWith(".")||fmts.endsWith("!")||fmts.endsWith("?")){
            fmts = fmts.concat(".");
        }
        //Takes away  

        for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){

        }
        return fmts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or is your title different f/ what ur asking? So you  need to only do the "Takes away" functoin? if so, pls change title

Comment: @Adel Please use whole words in your comments. This is not a text message :-)

Comment: First define "sentence".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ACL [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what you are really doing in your code

```
//you store uppercase version of first letter in `temp`
temp = fmts.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
//now you replace first letter with upper-cased one
fmts = fmts.replaceFirst(fmts.substring(0,1), temp);
```

and now time for your mistake

```
//here you are storing in `fmts` as lower-case part **after** first letter
//so `fmts =" Abcd"` becomes `fmts = "bcd"`
fmts = fmts.substring(1,str.length()-1).toLowerCase();
```

To correct it you can add `temp` value at start of new string like

```
fmts = temp + fmts.substring(1).toLowerCase();//BTW you can use `substring(1)` 
                                      //instead of `substring(1,str.length()-1)`
```

Comment: I did that and I am still getting "h" as the first character. :P

Comment: @CameronCarter can you post sentence you are using in your tests?

Comment: @CameronCarter Also can you post how you are using your method? I suspect that you may not be resigning your string with result of this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = " hello world"
```

reduce spaces first (avoid spaces in the front)

```
str = str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

capitalize the first letter and lowercase everything else (add them both)

```
str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1,str.length()).toLowerCase();
```